# How do I hash strings in C++?

Tags: c++, string, hashtable, string-hashing

I'm currently learning about hash table. Hashing integers are easy, but my assignment is to hash strings.
I have given strings:

```
25674316-6058714                
56105665-7450612                
96917015-1417157                
48189873-3313151
```

I have to hash them to fit into array of buckets[4].
How do I hash strings?

Comment: `size_t hash = std::hash<std::string>()(myString);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [standard libraries hash function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash):

```
std::string stringToHash = "25674316-6058714";
size_t result = std::hash<std::string>()(stringToHash);
```